# How do I define a dependency in 2GMP for certain Salesforce feature like Quote object?

Tags: salesforcedx, package-dependency, feature-management, feature-activation, 2gmp

How do I define a dependency in 2GMP for certain Salesforce feature like Quote object?

I need to release a package extension which should depend on Quote object.

How should I define such dependency?

In 1GMP, it is enought just to include dependency in the code and it is automatically detected. What is the corresponding process for 2GMP?

I receive the following errors when I try to release my extension package

```
referenceTo value of 'Quote' does not resolve to a valid sObject type,
Quote is not available in this org due to insufficient privileges.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `"definitionFile": "config/project-scratch-def.json",` should be included in the sfdx-project.json file as following

```
{
    "packageDirectories": [
        {
            "path": "force-app",
            "default": true,
            "package": "Baseline",
            "versionName": "1.0.0",
            "versionNumber": "1.0.0.NEXT"
        },
        {
            "path": "quote",
            "package": "Quote Extension",
            "versionName": "QE 0.0.0",
            "versionNumber": "0.0.0.NEXT",
            "definitionFile": "config/project-scratch-def.json",
            "dependencies": [
                {
                    "package": "Baseline",
                    "versionNumber": "1.0.0.LATEST"
                }
            ],
            "default": false
        },
```

and the file `config/project-scratch-def.json` should exist and contain `"quoteSettings": {"enableQuote": true}` lines like following:

```
{
    "orgName": "Package Development",
    "edition": "Enterprise",
    "features": [],
    "settings": {
        "quoteSettings": {
            "enableQuote": true
        }
    }
}
```